# calling model class function in controller in MVC

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

How can I call `model` class function in the `controller` class ? Like I have data in `$_POST` from the `View` file. Now I want to insert that data into `Mongo DB` through `model` class. I am using `yiiframework` MVC.

Comment: if your model were named `user` you can do `user::model()->myfunction()`

Comment: I am getting Error: Call to undefined function.

Comment: With all due respect I think you need to look at the documentation, `myfunction` was just an example name designed to be replaced with your name

Answer (score 0):

With the MVC programming pattern you needed to initialize a model object when the controller was built.  This the same thing you did with the view.  The nice thing about MVC is that your $_POST will follow your function chain and you will not have to pass the array to each function.

```
controller{
  public $view = null;
  public $model = null;

  function __construct(){
    $this->view = new View();
    $this->model = new Model();
  }

  function form_submit(){
    $this->model->insertDB_func();  // whatever your func is
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just the basic sense of MVC and not specific to yiiframework or Mongo DB

Comment: my controller class name is : SiteController.php  . I have made the constructor as u mentioned and call the function AddMeeting() but still I am getting error.:

Comment: Error: include(Model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example

```
public function actionViewContact()
{
   $contact = new Contact; // you can also do Contact::model(); 
   $contact->scenario='add';
   if (isset($_POST['Contact'])) 
   {
      $contact->attributes = $_POST['Contact'];
      $contact->save(); // calling save function in contact model which is activerecord
   }
}
```

Comment: My model class name is "ActivityForm". Here it is:

Comment: This is my model class :<?php
class ActivityForm extends  CFormModel
{
public $Address;
public $Description;
public $Company;
public $DATE;
public $BookingNum;
public $CP;
public $Email;
public $PN;
public $URL;

 public function AddMeeting()
 {

 $doc =array(
    "Address"=> $Address,
    "Description"=>$Description,
    "Company"=>$Compnay,
    "DATE"=>$DATE,
    "BookingNum"=>$BookingNum,
    "CP"=>$CP,
    "Email"=>$Email,
    "PN"=>$PN,
    "URL"=>$URL);

 } // end function AddMeeting

}
?>   can u tell me how can i store $_POST data into MongoDb using this model class..

Comment: my controller code is same as yours... :| but my code doesnt get inside if check.. My $_POST is getting values as I have checked it by print_r.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm how are you requiring the model at the top of your controller? I've gotten into issues when deep into a mvc because the include path is back where the original call was made. Check out your include path with

get_include_path()

&& what files are included with

get_included_files()